# Next Post Link not working with parameters to restrict to same term

Tags: theme-development, next-post-link

I am using [next_post_link()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link) , and I want to use the parameters shown in the documentation to restrict it to go to the next post with the same term for a custom taxonomy called "years".

The line I am using is

`<?php next_post_link( '%link', __( 'Next', 'twentyeleven' ), TRUE, '', 'years' ); ?>`

This does not display a "next" link at all. However, when I remove the optional parameters, it does display the "next" link.

The page in question is http://stage.newurbanarts.org/mentors/alejandra-peralta/ (htaccess username: guest / password: stackexchange).

I put some debugging code into it near the top to show the output of `the_taxonomies()` and `the_terms()`.

It should show the "Next" link which would go to http://stage.newurbanarts.org/mentors/alison-rutsch/ - note in the debugging code that this post has the same terms for "years".

Update: I enabled some debugging - printing all the warnings on the page resulted in the page being unintelligible with many warnings coming from various plugins. I put all the info into [this log file](http://pastebin.com/S0Vg01yt), and the screen now displays where the "next" link should be:

> WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') WHERE p.post_date > '2013-09-30 12:05:35' AND p.post_type = 'mentors' AND p.po' at line 1]
> SELECT p.* FROM wp_posts AS p INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.taxonomy = 'category' AND tt.term_id IN () WHERE p.post_date > '2013-09-30 12:05:35' AND p.post_type = 'mentors' AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND tt.taxonomy = 'category' ORDER BY p.post_date ASC LIMIT 1

===

WordPress 3.4.1 (It's an old site that I just picked up for an organization that has not updated it for a while. Depends on many old plugins, so upgrading may break things, but I will give that a shot as per the answers.)

[Full code on github](https://github.com/mrengy/new-urban-arts).

Also, here's [just the template file in question](https://github.com/mrengy/new-urban-arts/blob/master/wp-content/themes/newurbanarts/single-mentors.php).

Comment: The `excluded_terms` param should be just `''`, not a space `' '`

Comment: @bonger I removed the space and updated the question and the staging server. Still getting the same result.

Comment: Mmm, very odd, just tried adding the same `next_post_link()` to one of my own sites with a custom taxonomy and it worked - but I see you're debugging it so I'll leave you to it!...

Comment: @bonger thanks. Not sure how to fix the SQL syntax from the error. I updated the question with said wordpress error. Let me know if you have ideas on that. My SQL knowledge is not great.

Comment: Why can't you update WordPress?

Comment: 3.4.1, Really? I don't want to sound rude or anything, but you are light years behind and missing out on some great features

Comment: @BradDalton It's a site that I just picked up for an organization that has been using it for a while. Kind of a mess depending on various outdated plugins, so I'm not sure if upgrading WP will break them. Will give upgrading a shot...

Comment: Good move. Take backup of WordPress files first just in case they where modified and edit your question to include the new version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Back with WordPress 3.4.1 the function [`next_post_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link) did not have - see [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4-branch/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1323) - the `$taxonomy` parameter, so it won't work, no matter what. IIRC the parameter is available since WP 3.8 or 3.9 - but those are pretty old too.

Just to say that very clearly, *do **NOT** use such a old version(s) of WP.*

Comment: As for the generated SQL the empty `IN ()` clause (`... AND tt.term_id IN (__there_must_be_something_in_here__)...`) is what causes it to fail.

Comment: Rarely had a problem with the parameter, when used with a version that actually supports it. So this is the first step, should it not work afterwards, then we can talk further. @webtoure

Comment: Oh, my explanation was just in case anybody was curios (as I was) about it. :) Of course **not** using this old 3.4.1 version is the first step. It doesn't surprise me that these old versions are alive since a lot of people are **also** running PHP versions < 5.3.0 for "no reason" (it's about legacy code of course).

Comment: Looking at the [WordPress usage statistics](https://wordpress.org/about/stats/) makes me wonder in disbelieve every time.. @webtoure

Comment: It's a site that I just picked up for an organization that has been using it for a while. Kind of a mess depending on various outdated plugins, so I'm not sure if upgrading WP will break them. Will give upgrading a shot...

Comment: I would say, you kind of have to, otherwise you only can implement a workaround of some sorts and it gets even messier. Do not forget to make a complete backup of the status quo, so all the files (WP,theme,plug-ins) and the database. Personally I would even say, get rid of - or replace - the things no longer compatible with the current version of WordPress. Because, all things considered, there is just no good reason for using such a outdated version. I know it is sometimes a hard sell to the clients, but not doing - or at least trying - it is kind of irresponsible. @MikeEng

Answer (score -1):

I was able to make it working by dropping the **$excluded_terms = ''**

```
next_post_link( '%link', __( 'Next', 'twentyeleven' ), true, '', 'years' );
next_post_link( '%link', __( 'Next', 'twentyeleven' ), true, 'years' );
```

Comment: I tried that, but I got a slightly longer WordPress Database Error: http://pastebin.com/wH2hNLNj